# Rhodes: Can't detect NDK toolchain path (corrupted NDK installation?)

Tags: android, ruby, linux, rhomobile, rhodes

I have installed rhodes and android SDK and NDK

OS: Linux Mint 16 X64, Ruby: ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux], SDK: Android.SDK.Release.v23.0.2.Linux, NDK: android-ndk32-r10-linux-x86_64 or android-ndk-r7b

and build.yml content:

```
#sdk: "/home/abolfazl/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.12"
sdkversion: 3.5.0
name: testapp
version: 1.0
vendor: rhomobile
build: debug
bbver: 4.6
applog: rholog.txt
iphone:
  configuration: Release
  sdk: iphonesimulator5.0
  provisionprofile:
  codesignidentity:
  entitlements:
  BundleIdentifier: com.rhomobile.testapp
  BundleURLScheme: testapp
wp:
  productid: '0ed4fa10-0f72-0132-4dc5-3870f4a0dbeb'
symbian:
  uid: '0xee1f6bcc'
android:
  version: 4.2.2

extensions: ["json", "another-extension"]
```

sdk manager:

[image: sdk_manager]

when I run rake run:android:

> cd
>   /home/abolfazl/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.12
>   $app_config['extensions'] : ["json", "another-extension"]
>   $app_config['capabilities'] : [] $vendor = rhomobile $app_package_name
>   = com.rhomobile.testapp rake aborted! Can't detect NDK toolchain path (corrupted NDK installation?)
>
> Tasks: TOP => run:android => run:android:emulator =>
>   config:android:emulator => config:android (See full trace by running
>   task with --trace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rhodes gem v3.5 was updated on github some times ago to adapt from changes in the newer NDKs (v3.5 was released around release 7 of the NDK).

Newer rhodes (latest is v5) directly supports the new NDKs.

Another thing is that rhodes still needs Ruby v1.9.3, seems that you're using it under Ruby v2.1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define path to Android NDK at <rhodes>/rhobuild.yml file. Or just run <rhodes>/bin/rhodes-setup